# Search for Pattern in list : python Regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pattern-matching

After the Data Analysis & getting the Required Result I'm appending that result to a List 
Now I Need to Retrieve Or Separate the Result (Search For Pattern & Obtain It)

Code:

```
data = []
data.append('\n'.join([' -> '.join(e) for e in paths]))
```

List Contais This data:

```
CH_Trans -> St_1 -> WDL
TRANSFER_Trn -> St_1
Access_Ltd -> MPL_Limited
IPIPI -> TLC_Pvt_Ltd
234er -> Three_Star_Services -> Asian_Pharmas -> PPP_Channel
Sonata_Ltd -> Three_Star_Services
Arc_Estates -> Russian_Hosp
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
G -> H
ZN_INTBNKOUT_SET -> -2008_1 -> X
ZZ_1_ -> AA_2 -> AA_3 -> ZZ_1_
XYZ- -> ABC -> XYZ-
SSS -> BBB -> SSS
Rock_8CC -> Russ -> By_sus -> Rock_8CC

Note : Display or Retrieve Pattern Which has more than two symbol of type[->]
( Txt -> txt -> txt )
```

I'm Trying to get it Done by Regex

```
for i in data:
    regex = ("\w+\s->\s\w+\s->\s\w+")             
    match = re.findall(regex, i,re.MULTILINE)
    print(match)

Regex Expression I Tried But Unable to get Requried Result
#\w+\s->\s\w+\s->\s\w+
#\w+\s[-][>]\s\w+\s[-][>]\s\w+
#\w+\s[-][>]\s\w+\s[-][>]\s\w+\s[-][>]\s\w+

Result I Got
['CH_Trans-> St_1-> WDL', '234er -> Three_Star_Services -> Asian_Pharmas',
 'A -> B -> C', 'D -> E -> F', 'ZZ_1_ -> AA_2 -> AA_3', 
'SSS -> BBB -> SSS', 'Rock_8CC -> Russ -> By_sus']
```

Requried Result What I want to Obtain is

```
----Pattern I------
CH_Trans -> St_1 -> WDL
234er -> Three_Star_Services -> Asian_Pharmas -> PPP_Channel
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
ZN_INTBNKOUT_SET -> -2008_1 -> X


# Pattern II Consists of Patterns which are same i.e[ Fist_ele & Last_Ele Is Same]
----Pattern II------
ZZ_1_ -> AA_2 -> AA_3 -> ZZ_1_
XYZ- -> ABC -> XYZ-
SSS -> BBB -> SSS
Rock_8CC -> Russ -> By_sus -> Rock_8CC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following as a starting point:

```
regex = r'^\S+(?:\s->\s\S+){2,}$'
for i in data:
    m = re.match(regex, i)
    if (m):
        print(m.group())
```

Results (Pattern I + Pattern II):

```
CH_Trans -> St_1 -> WDL
234er -> Three_Star_Services -> Asian_Pharmas -> PPP_Channel
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
ZN_INTBNKOUT_SET -> -2008_1 -> X
ZZ_1_ -> AA_2 -> AA_3 -> ZZ_1_
XYZ- -> ABC -> XYZ-
SSS -> BBB -> SSS
Rock_8CC -> Russ -> By_sus -> Rock_8CC
```

Explanation of the regex `^\S+(?:\s->\s\S+){2,}$`:

```
^\S+       start with non-blank string
(?: ... )  grouping
\s->\s\S+  a blank followed by "->" followed by a blank and non-blank string
{2,}       repeats the previous pattern (or group) two or more times
$          end of the string
```

As of pattern II please say:

```
regex = r'^(\S+)(?:\s->\s\S+){1,}\s->\s\1$'
for i in data:
    m = re.match(regex, i)
    if (m):
        print(m.group())
```

Results:

```
ZZ_1_ -> AA_2 -> AA_3 -> ZZ_1_
XYZ- -> ABC -> XYZ-
SSS -> BBB -> SSS
Rock_8CC -> Russ -> By_sus -> Rock_8CC
```

Explanation of regex `r'^(\S+)(?:\s->\s\S+){1,}\s->\s\1$'`:

```
- ^(\S+)     captures the 1st element and assigns \1 to it
- (?: ... )  grouping
- \s->\s\S+  a blank followed by "->" followed by a blank and non-blank string
- {1,}       repeats the previous pattern (or group) one or more times
- \s->\s\1   a blank followed by "->" followed by a blank and the 1st element \1
- $          end of the string
```

In order to obtain the result of pattern I, we may need to subtract the list of pattern II from the 1st results.
If we could say:

```
regex = r'^(\S+)(?:\s->\s\S+){2,}(?<!\1)$'
```

it will exclude the string whose last element differs from the 1st element then we could obtain the result of pattern I directry but the regex causes the error saying `"group references in lookbehind assertions"` so far.